# Disable the Network Drive from the SaveFileDialog() in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, savefiledialog

How could I disable/hide/remove the Network Drive from the SaveFileDialog() in C#?
Here is the demo code for reference.

```
 using (var browsDlg = new SaveFileDialog())
 {
    browsDlg.Title = "Save File";
    // What should be written here to hide the Network Path
    
    if (browsDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       // Something.......
    }   
 }
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if your user wants to save the file on a network share?

Comment: Just for the sake of security, I don't want users to save in the Network path.

Comment: You can install Microsoft's  Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell NuGet package and use the `CommonSaveFileDialog`. The dialogs expose a `FolderChanging` event. You can handle it to check if the opening folder is a Network folder and cancel opening using the event args.

Comment: Otherwise you can always show an error message to force the user to pick a different destination. You should programmatically re-open the dialog for the user after the message.

Comment: @BionicCode But how can I hide the Network icon from the Dialog(left bottom side).

Comment: You can't. This is not a framework level dialog. It's the OS dialog hosted in a framework container to allow some degree of convenient interaction with the application. You must delegate the responsibility to choose a secure destination to the user. If your application is *required* to enforce certain security policies, you must either ask the user to verify the location after communicating the security risks or reject particular locations by displaying a corresponding dialog or create a custom dialog. A custom dialog is not that much of an effort. You can even use the original OS icons.

Comment: Have a look at [Customizing your FileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/march/cutting-edge-customize-your-open-file-dialog). It is fairly old, and I'm not sure if it still works.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the user's chosen path by following method, and if the user chooses the network path, display the appropriate message for him or her:

```
    string FileSavePath;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        switch (FBD.ShowDialog())
        {
            case DialogResult.OK:
                FileSavePath = FBD.SelectedPath.Substring(0,2);
                switch (FileSavePath == @"\\")
                {
                    case true:
                        MessageBox.Show(null, "You are not allowed to use the network path", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
                        FileSavePath = null;
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Tested in:

Visual Studio 2017,
.NET Framework 4.5.2,
Windows Forms

Thanks

Comment: Note: if this solution helps you, please mark as answer (don't forget to vote for me).

Comment: Isn't it a bit weird, to give the operator the possibility to click on a button, but if he does, you show him that he shouldn't do that? Wouldn't it be better to at least disable the button but preferably don't show it at all?

Comment: Do you know a better solution?

Comment: My advice: don't show folders that the operator shouldn't select. Read [Customizing your OpenFileDialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2003/march/cutting-edge-customize-your-open-file-dialog). Works similar for SaveFileDialog